# Как в таблице гугл формулой собрать ряды дат в один, без создания доп. вычисляемых диапазонов

Tags: массивы, google-spreadsheet, таблицы

Друзья, подскажите, какую функцию можно использовать для склеивания нескольких рядов дат в один, одной функцией (формулой). Без промежуточных вычислений не нахожу вариантов, решаю через создание вычисляемых диапазонов с SEQUENCE() и формулы массива, но не получаю нужный результат. Уверен, у гугл таблиц припасён вариант и проще и красивее - хотя бы намекните, дальше сам дотямаю
[Таблица с примером тут](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r1nAyuVSMpfmdjQoeFE2ysAY2w3Cm62H9q7tNxKc8fo/edit?usp=sharing) Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=TOROW(BYROW(A4:C7;LAMBDA(row;SEQUENCE(1;ИНДЕКС(row;;2);ИНДЕКС(row;;1);1)));1)
```

Comment: Александр, благодарю за красивое решение!

Comment: @SergeyShvetsov примите ответ (серая галочка слева)